# Can couch db be used for a document repository?

Tags: couchdb

We currently use DFS to manage nearly 1 TB of data (this data is primarily MS Office documents). Currently users go in, edit their doc, dfs syncs it across a few nodes, and voila!

Unfortunately this has been giving us headaches recently and I'd like to come up with a more viable solution, (the specific headaches are users randomly deleting files, peerlock not working as the user anticipated etc...)

Doing some research it seems like couchdb could provide similar functionality to dfs/ so my question(s) are:

1. Does couchdb support MS Office documents/formats?
2. If it doesn't is there anything else I could do short of developing our own app?

Answer (score 1):

Couchdb is a "document" store, meaning it stores structured documents. However, the structure is JSON, not MS office documents. That said, couchdb does have support for binary attachments to documents.

1. Couchdb can store any file as an attachment - it doesn't have support for specific formats. Couch does automatically compress some types. You can specify compressible file-types your couchdb config. Other than that, couchdb has no special handling of documents by mime-type.
2. You will likely have to develop some sort of user-facing interface in any case. Users will not know how to use the couchdb REST api, or even the futon administrative UI.